# Random new line created without input

Tags: python

This is for Day 6 of the 30 Days of Code Challenge on Hackerrank. I have tested my code in my own IDE and it runs fine, but whenever I enter it into the Hackerrank IDE it randomly puts separates the first loop onto two lines.

input:

> 2 
> Hacker 
> Rank

```
import sys

T = int(input())
for lines in sys.stdin:
    print(lines[::2]+ " " + lines[1::2])
```

The output is meant to be

> Hce akr 
> Rn ak

which is what I get on my IDE, but instead I'm getting

> Hce 
> akr 
> Rn ak

With a space before the akr. Is it broken or my mistake?

Comment: Try doing `lines[::2]`.strip('\n')` and `lines[1::2].strip('\n')`. The newline at the end of the line is getting included, it looks like. Maybe HackerRank's input uses `\r\n` instead of `\n` and python is getting confused.

Comment: "or my mistake" - yes, it is your mistake. You forgot about the linebreaks (`\n`) at the end of each line in stdin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the whitespace.

**Input:**
2

Hacker

Rank

```
import sys

T = int(input())
for lines in sys.stdin:
    print(lines[::2].strip()+ " " + lines[1::2].strip())
```

**OutPut:**

2

Hce akr

Rn ak

I tested the code on ipython and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip off the newline `\n` character at the end of input.

```
import sys

T = int(input())
for lines in sys.stdin:
    lines = lines.strip('\n')
    print(lines[::2]+ " " + lines[1::2])
```

```
Output:

2
Hacker
Rank
Hce akr
Rn ak
```